# How can I set the maximum number of object to show?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which create automatically a new `option` if there is a folder inside. But the last folder is contain a HTML file and that HTML is going to be opened automatically when select the parent folder. In this case I don't want to create another `option`.

This is my code which create new levels so I want to stop it to create a new one once there are 4 `option` levels created:

```
function processNewDFData( respObj, $currentSelectItem, strCurrentPath ) {
  fsStructure[strCurrentPath] = {'subfolders':[], 'subshtmls':[]};
  if ( (respObj.subfolders.length > 0) || (respObj.subshtmls.length > 0) ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < respObj.subfolders.length; i++ ) {
      fsStructure[strCurrentPath].subfolders.push( respObj.subfolders[i] );
    }

    for( var i = 0; i < respObj.subshtmls.length; i++ ) {
      fsStructure[strCurrentPath].subshtmls.push( respObj.subshtmls[i] );
    }
  }

  rendSelects( $currentSelectItem, strCurrentPath );
}
```

Comment: This code hurts my eyes...

Comment: better now? I want to set the length for subfolders to be maximum 4

Comment: what is wrong with checking `fsStructure[strCurrentPath].subfolders.lengh`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean